# Show/hide Grid Row when mouse is over grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Grid with two rows which are aligned at the bottom of my window.

By default the top row is always visible and the bottom is hidden. What I would like is when the mouse is over the grid, for the bottom row to display with animation rising up from the bottom.

Could someone help me with this.

Comment: What is in the bottom row of the grid?

Comment: A bunch of buttons in a horizontal stackpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the buttons in a panel, say a StackPanel, and place the StackPanel in the bottom row.

Then add a RenderTransform to the panel and animate the transform.